# How to define two MySQL database connections in Sails.js

Tags: mysql, sails.js

Using sails.js v0.10 rc8, my app had 1 connection to a mysql database and I would liked for a given model that the data are fetched from another database.

Is it possible ? If yes, how to acheive this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can define multiple connections and set each model to use a different one.  Please see the [documentation on connections](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/sails.config/sails.config.connections.md) for a full review.

You can set up as many connections as you need in your **config/connections.js** file.  You can even set up multiple connections using the same adapter:

```
module.exports.connections = {
  // A MySQL connection
  mysql1: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    user: 'root',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'database1'
  },
  // Another MySQL connection, same server, different database
  mysql2: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    user: 'root',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'database2'
  },
  // A Postgresql connection
  postgres: {
    adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'mypsqldb'
  }
};
```

Then in your model class file, specify the connection to use for that model:

```
module.exports = {
    connection: 'mysql1',
    attributes: {...}
}
```

To specify the default connection for models, set it in **config/models.js**:

```
module.export.models = {
    connection: 'mysql2'
};
```